# can not stop NSTimer

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSTimer doesn't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031554/nstimer-doesnt-stop)

I hope to stop a running NSTimer, below are my codes:

```
timer=[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10       
       target:self
     selector:@selector(timerFired:)
     userInfo:nil
      repeats:NO] retain];
```

the function that stops the timer

```
-(void)stopTimer;
{

  [timer invalidate];
  [timer release];
   timer = nil;

}
```

But I found that even I called 'stopTimer', the timer did not stop and 'timerFired' would be triggered.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should never retain a reference which is not yours. References created without using alloc/new aren't yours so don't retain nor release them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't retain it, don't release it.