# How to stop/invalidate a NSTimer

Tags: ios4, timer, ios-simulator, nstimer, iphone-sdk-4.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSTimer doesn't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031554/nstimer-doesnt-stop)

How can I stop / invalidate a NSTimer??

Below is the code:

```
- (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer {

   NSLog(@"Each & Every Time this MEthods is called Even if I try to invalidate it in viewDidDisappear "); 
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if (autoscrollTimer == nil) {
        autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(35.0/1000.0)
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:) 
                                                         userInfo:nil 
                                                          repeats:YES]; // To repeat this thread it's as per my requirement
    }
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [autoscrollTimer invalidate];
}
```

So,please suggest me to do this ...

Comment: Are you sure [autoscrollTimer invalidate] is called?  And that it references the same object created in viewWillAppear?

Comment: yes this is called & even then the timer doesn't stop...why ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I guess you have made it as property nonatomic, retain?

Please do this:

```
[self.autoscrollTimer invalidate];
```

Thanks.