# IOS: stop a NSTimer

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSTimer doesn't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031554/nstimer-doesnt-stop)

I have this code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:110.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

- (void) targetMethod:(NSTimer) timer{
NSLog(@"Hello World");}
```

in targetMethod I can stop timer with [timer invalidate], but out of this method, How can I stop targetMethod?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can keep your `NSTimer` in a variable and stop the timer using the `invalidate` method. Like the following:

```
NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:110.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

[myTimer invalidate];
```

Answer (score 17):

One way to do it is to create NSTimer *timer; as a global variable so you can have a handle to the timer.  Some thing likes this:

```
NSTimer *timer;  //global var

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:110.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

To stop timer somewhere in the same class:

```
[timer invalidate];
```