# NSTimer not invalidating even after trying main thread solution

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have set a NSTimer and have tried invalidating it but the timer still triggers the selector. I have already tried what many threads have suggested and set and invalidated the timer on the main thread.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking for help.

Comment: In my experience, this is generally called by accidentally starting multiple timers. I'd suggest putting a log statement everywhere you start and `invalidate` timers. I bet you'll find a unbalanced pair somewhere.

Comment: @JonathanMee I have added code to it.

Comment: @AceN: we don't know how @Alexis code looked, but he was using `NSTimer`, you `Timer`. Please open a new question with your issue and leave a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by invalidating the timer before re instantiating it.

Before:

```
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.hide), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

After:

```
    self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.hide), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Yep, that would do it. You were discarding the only reference you had to that old timer. You should go ahead and accept your own answer (as strange as that feels).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. This was the only thing that worked for me:

Start the timer:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target:self, selector:#selector(timerMethod), userInfo:nil, repeats: false)
```

And then in timerMethod:

```
func timerMethod() {
     // do what you need to do

     if (needs to be called again) {

         NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target:self, selector:#selector(timerMethod), userInfo:nil, repeats: false)        
     }
}
```

This was the only way I got it to work. Taken from here: [NSTimer doesn't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031554/nstimer-doesnt-stop) it is Mona's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you created it on a separate thread it won't invalidate.

Doc for `invalidate()` says

> You must send this message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.